# How to extract people who've done installation and repair type jobs

Tags: excel

In the example provided, I want to find mobile phone D and C. What would be the criteria for this?

[image: Example]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code and the errors you might have.

Comment: Can you explain how your question title relates to the screen shot, specifically the "installs and repair type jobs" part?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes the screenshot shows what has been tried, though, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

To show phone D and phone C in the results, you have to specify both phones in the Advanced Filter criteria, one phone per row.

For examples on how to use complex filter criteria in Advanced Filter, see

https://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html